# The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, httpwebrequest, media-type

I try to upload a text file from **WPF RESTful client to ASP .NET MVC WebAPI 2 website**.

**Client code**

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("http://localhost:22678/api/Account/UploadFile?fileName=test.txt&description=MyDesc1");

request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + tokenModel.ExternalAccessToken);  
request.ContentType = "text/plain";
request.MediaType = "text/plain";
byte[] fileToSend = File.ReadAllBytes(@"E:\test.txt");  
request.ContentLength = fileToSend.Length;

using (Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
      // Send the file as body request. 
      requestStream.Write(fileToSend, 0, fileToSend.Length);
      requestStream.Close();
}

using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                        Console.WriteLine("HTTP/{0} {1} {2}", response.ProtocolVersion, (int)response.StatusCode, response.StatusDescription);
```

**WebAPI 2 code**

```
[HttpPost]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("UploadFile")]
public void UploadFile(string fileName, string description, Stream fileContents)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[32768];
    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
    int bytesRead, totalBytesRead = 0;
    do
    {
        bytesRead = fileContents.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
        totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

        ms.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
    } while (bytesRead > 0);

   var data = ms.ToArray() ;

    ms.Close();
    Debug.WriteLine("Uploaded file {0} with {1} bytes", fileName, totalBytesRead);
}
```

So.. Under the client code I am facing that exception

> The remote server returned an error: (415) Unsupported Media Type.

Any clue what do I am missing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

+1 on what Radim has mentioned above...As per your action Web API model binding notices that the parameter `fileContents` is a complex type and by default assumes to read the request body content using the formatters. (note that since `fileName` and `description` parameters are of  `string` type, they are expected to come from uri by default).

You can do something like the following to prevent model binding to take place:

```
[HttpPost]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("UploadFile")]
public async Task UploadFile(string fileName, string description)
{
   byte[] fileContents = await Request.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();

   ....
}
```

BTW, what do you plan to do with this `fileContents`? are you trying to create a local file? if yes, there is a better way to handle this.

**Update based on your last comment**:

A quick example of what you could do

```
[HttpPost]
[HostAuthentication(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalBearer)]
[Route("UploadFile")]
public async Task UploadFile(string fileName, string description)
{
    Stream requestStream = await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

    //TODO: Following are some cases you might need to handle
    //1. if there is already a file with the same name in the folder
    //2. by default, request content is buffered and so if large files are uploaded
    //   then the request buffer policy needs to be changed to be non-buffered to imporve memory usage
    //3. if exception happens while copying contents to a file

    using(FileStream fileStream = File.Create(@"C:\UploadedFiles\" + fileName))
    {
        await requestStream.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
    }

    // you need not close the request stream as Web API would take care of it
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Yes I have to create a local file. In fact I need solution to send ZIP file to WebAPI method from WPF RESTFil client. Could u help with that pls?

Comment: @ClarkKent, Kiran Challa, great job! Good luck with Web API

Comment: I'm doing something similar except when I call "await Request.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();" I get an invalid operation exception.

Answer (score 15):

You are setting the `ContentType = "text/plain"`, and this settings drive the Formatter selection. Please check [**Media Formatters**](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters) for more details.

An extract:

> In Web API, the media type determines how Web API serializes and
>   deserializes the HTTP message body. There is built-in support for XML,
>   JSON, and form-urlencoded data, and you can support additional media
>   types by writing a media formatter.

So, there is no built in text/plain formatter, ie: *Unsupported Media Type*. You can change the content-type to some supported, built-in, or implement custome one (as described in the [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/media-formatters))

Comment: Thank you! In fact I need to send ZIP archive. What do I have to do in that case? Could you help with that please?

Comment: I would say you need an "upload file" functionality. Please check this: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/henrikn/archive/2012/03/01/file-upload-and-asp-net-web-api.aspx, the **Creating an ApiController**. This is the way how to take a file passed, and process it on the server... I would say ;) Formatters are for a *standard* communication ala JSON or XML

Comment: @RadimKöhler: In general, we always do not need a multipart upload kind of functionality to upload a file.

Comment: @KiranChalla, I am mostly trying to say: the formatter is not we need here. We are about the processing the stream (file) passed, rather wokring with Media Formatters via Content Type. But yeah ;) ... this is what the OP would need